# With BeautifulSoup I can't find some elements

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, element

[image from the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi2Ay.png) I am trying to get what is under "col-12 col-md-3 product-grid-item-container rendered-enhanced" with running this script

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'

}
r = requests.get('https://www.sneaksup.com/search?q=dunk&pagenumber=1', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
hrefs = soup.find('div', class_='product-list-inner-container bg-white')
print(hrefs)
```

but unfortunately all I got is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwWW8.png) . How can I get all of the info above the "col-12 col-md-3 product-grid-item-container rendered-enhanced"(I tried to find from:

```
hrefs = soup.find('div', class_='col-12 col-md-3 product-grid-item-container rendered-enhanced')
```

but only got [ ] )

Comment: Hey @emir Welcome to SO! please dont share codes as images edit your post and copy paste your code with proper description and Output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, you can get that dat from the api endpoint. Here's how you'd do that:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'

}

url = 'https://www.sneaksup.com/search?q=dunk&pagenumber=1&paginationType=20&orderby=0'
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['Products'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Data you are looking for it might not be visible through class but what you can do manually search for title of product so from that you can find in script tag

```
text=soup.find_all("script")[5].contents[0]
```

after using above code we can extract text using `re` module

```
import re
main_data=re.findall(r'\{.*?\}', text)
```

In which `main_data` return as list of dictionary and you can extract what so ever data you want

Answer (score 0):

That URL loads data from an API endpoint.

You can get everything related to product from that Endpoint.

Here is the Endpoint

```
https://www.sneaksup.com/search?q=dunk&pagenumber=1&paginationType=20&orderby=0
```